# How to correctly add Google Analytics to a Next.js app without an _app.js or _document.js?

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-analytics

I'm trying to integrate Google Analytics into my Next.js application, but I'm facing some issues. I don't have an _app.js or _document.js file in my project structure, and when I add the GA script to my layout.tsx component, it doesn't seem to be injected into the page.

Here's my layout.tsx file:

```js
import "./css/style.css";

import { Inter } from "next/font/google";

import Header from "@/components/ui/header";
import Head from "next/head";
// import Banner from '@/components/banner'

const inter = Inter({
  subsets: ["latin"],
  variable: "--font-inter",
  display: "swap",
});

export const metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <Head>
        {/* Standard metadata */}
        <meta charSet="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>{metadata.title}</title>
        <meta name="description" content={metadata.description} />
        <link rel="icon" href="/images/logo.png" />

        {/* Google Analytics */}
        <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=someid"></script>
        <script
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
            __html: `
              window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
              function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
              gtag('js', new Date());
              gtag('config', 'someid');
            `,
          }}
        />
      </Head>
      <body
        className={`${inter.variable} font-inter antialiased bg-white text-gray-900 tracking-tight`}
      >
        <div className="flex flex-col min-h-screen overflow-hidden supports-[overflow:clip]:overflow-clip">
          <Header />
          <link rel="icon" href="/images/logo.png" />
          {children}
          {/* <Banner /> */}
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

I've added the Google Analytics script inside the `<Head>` component, but when I inspect the page or use Google Tag Assistant, the script doesn't show up.

My project structure is as follows:

```
- app
  - (default)
    - layout.tsx
  - components
    - ui
    - utils
- pages
  - page.tsx
- public
- styles
```

I'm expecting the Google Analytics script to be inserted into the `<head>` of my document, but it's not happening. What am I missing or doing wrong?

Any help on how to correctly integrate Google Analytics into this setup would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to add this in your layout.tsx but your **index.html** which is located in your public folder. The head-tag is the proper place for it.

Also I am not sure if you just removed it, but you also have to replace "someid" with your actual Google Tag. This can be found in your Google-Analytics Account.

Comment: "someid" is just a placeholder i am using. i dont have a index.html. how can i add so that its also added to my application?

Comment: I edited the post. You find it in your public folder.

Comment: i dont have a html file in my public folder.